# Creating a model and its polymorphic associations in one 'create' call using Sequelize.js

Tags: sequelize.js

I've defined my models similarly to the following example from the documentation:
http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/associations/#nm

When I try to create a Post and its Tags in one go using the `Post.create` method, the post, the tags, and the "through" table row all get created, except that the `taggable` field doesn't get set on the "through" table, so the association does not get correctly defined.

If I create both the tag and the post separately, then I can use the `post.addTags` method to associate the tags and in that case everything works fine and the `taggable` field gets set as defined in the scope of the `Post.belongsToMany` association.

My question is, am I not passing correct options to the `Post.create` method or is using a "through" table with a scope to create associations in one go not supported by Sequelize?

Here's the creation code:

```js
models.Post.create({
  title: 'test',
  tags: [{
    name: 'tag1'
  }]
}, {
  include: [{
    model: models.Tag,
    as: 'tags',
    through: {
      model: models.ItemTag,
      scope: {
        taggable: 'post'
      }
    }
  }]
});
```

Here's the generated SQL:

```
Executing (default): INSERT INTO `posts` (`id`,`title`,`created_at`,`updated_at`) VALUES (DEFAULT,'test','2017-01-27 16:29:15','2017-01-27 16:29:15');
Executing (default): INSERT INTO `tags` (`id`,`name`,`created_at`,`updated_at`) VALUES (DEFAULT,'tag1','2017-01-27 16:29:15','2017-01-27 16:29:15');
Executing (default): INSERT INTO `item_tag` (`tag_id`,`taggable_id`,`created_at`,`updated_at`) VALUES (1,1,'2017-01-27 16:29:15','2017-01-27 16:29:15');
```

And here are my model definitions:

```js
// Post
export
default
function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var Post = sequelize.define('Post', {
    title: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        Post.belongsToMany(models.Tag, {
          as: 'tags',
          foreignKey: 'taggable_id',
          constraints: false,
          through: {
            model: models.ItemTag,
            unique: false,
            scope: {
              taggable: 'post'
            }
          }
        });
      }
    },
    tableName: 'posts',
    underscored: true
  });

  return Post;
};


// Tag
export
default
function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var Tag = sequelize.define('Tag', {
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        Tag.belongsToMany(models.Post, {
          as: 'posts',
          foreignKey: 'tag_id',
          constraints: false,
          through: {
            model: models.ItemTag,
            unique: false,
            scope: {
              taggable: 'posts'
            }
          }
        });
      }
    },
    tableName: 'tags',
    underscored: true
  });
  return Tag;
};

// ItemTag (the "through" table)
export
default
function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var ItemTag = sequelize.define('ItemTag', {
    tag_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      unique: 'item_tag',
      references: {
        model: 'tags',
        key: 'id'
      }
    },
    taggable_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      unique: 'item_tag'
    },
    taggable: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      unique: 'item_tag'
    },
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        ItemTag.belongsTo(models.Post, {
          foreignKey: 'taggable_id',
          constraints: false,
          scope: {
            taggable: 'post'
          }
        });

        ItemTag.belongsTo(models.Tag, {
          foreignKey: 'tag_id',
          constraints: false
        });
      }
    },
    tableName: 'item_tag',
    underscored: true
  });

  return ItemTag;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was actually a bug in Sequelize. I created a pull request for it, so the code above should work with the next release of Sequelize.
https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/pull/7181

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue on polymorphic 1:m relationships with one "create" call based on the Post --> Comment / Image --> Comment examples. Have you experienced the same?